# Can I use a 0.5 ohm power resistor along with a 13.6V regulated power supply, to current limit a 12V battery charging circuit?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, resistors, battery-charging

I have a 13.6V 10A continuous rated (12A peak rated) regulated power supply, that I use as a charger (and trickle charger), for a 12V AGM battery bank for an inverter setup that powers a shallow well pump during power outages.  What I don't want to happen is when the grid power comes back on, the 13.6V 10A power supply gets overloaded, cuz the battery bank is down around 12V and wants to draw more than 10 amps.  So I was wondering if I use a 0.5 ohm power resistor, if that will do the trick.  I can position it in front of a large fan so excessive heat should not be an issue.  So assuming the charger (power supply) and batteries plus wires already have maybe 0.5 ohms of total resistance, by adding 0.5 ohms more (thus making it perhaps 1 ohm total), is it safe to assume that I can just take 13.6V - 12.0V = 1.6V differential, and assume that at 1 ohm total resistance, the current would be limited to about 1.6A?  F.Y.I., the battery bank I am using is currently 12V and 300Ah rated (but will be getting larger in capacity).  It is ok if the bank takes up to 72 hours to recharge after being drained to 50% SoC, but the thing I want to avoid is drawing close to 10A from the power supply cuz it will likely get stressed out and get hot.  Also, does it make any significant difference if I put the 0.5 ohm power resistor on the + or - side of the DC?

The 300Ah rated battery bank consists of 4 identical 12V 75Ah rated AGM batteries, all in excellent health (checked individually on a 100A load tester).

Also, the power supply has an overload light indicator, so I am thinking it is possible to overload it based on that (not having the datasheet for it).

Comment: Data sheet for the 12 volt AGM battery?

Comment: Check the PSU's datasheet. It may have safe current limiting at its rated 10A, rendering further measures unnecessary. Otherwise, if your wiring is really 0.5 ohms, you'll get safe current limiting at 3A or so.

Comment: Here are some pointers: your 10A rated PSU, let’s assume it can run at 8A more comfortably. This is 8/300 = C/38 = a very slow charging, equivalent to 1 day with a 50% DoD. Further current reduction as 2~3A may not be the adequate to replenish all cells in a balanced way. There are other protection means you could try/adapt, to assure 13.6V x 8A for the longest time, using an external auxiliary circuit that throttles the PSU when either one (V.set or I.set) is reached. If you are still interested, I can elaborate more in a “formal” answer.